# Forgot the password type in the Ubuntu Linux for Windows during set up of bash Ubuntu

Tags: system-installation

A newbie trying to install to install, bash Ubuntu in windows 10. And mistake type unknown password due to the password not visible
To install other thing password requires.
What should I do now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows' Microsoft Store, uninstall Ubuntu then uninstall Windows Subsystem for Linux.

Reboot.

Go back into the Microsoft Store.

Reinstall Windows Subsystem for Linux.

Reinstall Ubuntu